# SSRS data set variables not read by the other data source query

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an issue in querying 2 datasets in SSRS. I have 4 datasets out of which 3 points to 1 data source and 1 point to the second data source.

The parameters of the report get the values from the datasets of 1 data source. Then once the parameters are assigned a value, I am using these to query the other data source to display the results. However, when I run the report, I get the following error:

> Declare a scalar variable @Date1.

It could be due to the data sources being on 2 separate servers.

Anybody faced this issue before?

Comment: it's been a while I have worked the last time with SSRS, but I remember that the order of data sources mattered. Meaning: the 1 data source needs to be accessed first, so that the other data sources can make use of this parameter.

Comment: A few things to check. `@Date1` must NOT be declared in your in the last dataset query. The parameter name referenced in your last dataset query must be exactly the same as the report parameter name - it is case sensitive. ALL references to `@Date1` in your dataset query must be the same case.. If this does not help, edit your question and show the last dataset query and the details of the related parameter.